# Is there any way to pass an argument to addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide all elements in a class (logos) except the element that is clicked on. So I wrote this out only to realize that it's impossible to pass arguments to functions activated by addEventListener! This seems... inflexible to say the least. Is there another obvious way to pass an argument that I'm blind to (I'm pretty new to Javascript)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<title>Sexism in Silicon Valley</title>
</head>
<body id="body1">
<div class="parent">
    <img src="kstartup.png" class="logos" id="id1">
    <img src="uber.png" class="logos" id="id2">
    <img src="kpcb.png" class="logos" id="id3">
    <img id="id4" src="r1startup.png" class="logos">
</div>
<div class="parent" id="parent2">
    <img src="zillow.png" class="logos" id="id5">
    <img src="github.png" class="logos" id="id6">
    <img src="tinde.png" class="logos" id="id7">
    <img src="snapchat.png" class="logos" id="id8">
</div>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function click(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < logos.length; i++) {
        if (x !== i) {
        logos[i].style.display = "hidden";
        }
    }

}

var logos = document.getElementsByClassName("logos");
for (var i = 0; i < logos.length; i++) {
    logos[i].addEventListener('click', click(i));
}
```

Comment: `...addEventListener('click', (function(i) { return function() { click(i); } })(i))`.

Comment: Check out **event delegation** which allows you to attach an event to a higher level element to capture events for its children.  You can use **event.target** to get information about the element which was clicked and you'll only need one event listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal answer to your question:

```
logos[i].addEventListener('click', (function(i) { return function() { click(i); } })(i));
```

will do what you want. You need a function to wrap `click(i)`, since you don't want to execute `click(i)` immediately; and you need another function to close over `i`, or you will get seemingly weird results (i.e. getting `click(logos.length)` always).

What you want to do instead is not use the iterator at all. Attach a listener to `#logos` itself; in the handler (which will get an `event` parameter), iterate over its children and compare to `event.target`.

Comment: But logos is a class, not an id, so wouldn't I have to iterate over the elements in the class to apply an addEventListener to all of them?

Comment: Err, I messed up a bit. Under the second proposal, you would attach a single listener to the parent of all `.logos`.

Comment: hm, and the parent would be an id, not a class, yes? Because I have a my logos split up in different divs with different parents, but I suppose I could just run it once for each parent id.

Comment: Doesn't need to be a parent, you could bind it to a common ancestor (or even `document`).